# How do I enable matrix variable support without clobbering Spring Boot configuration?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'd like to both use Spring Boot to take advantage of `JacksonAutoConfiguration` and enable matrix variables for my controllers, which requires calling `RequestMappingHandlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false)`.

When this [trivial Gist](https://gist.github.com/emersonf/a5bec01225f540b1a167) is run without the `WebMvcConfiguration` being scanned in, the output is

```
{"dateTime":1404244199372}
```

When it is scanned in, the output is

```
{"dateTime":{"year":2014,"era":1,"dayOfYear":182,"dayOfWeek":2,"dayOfMonth":1,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2014,"yearOfCentury":14,"weekyear":2014,"monthOfYear":7,"weekOfWeekyear":27,"secondOfDay":76856,"minuteOfDay":1280,"hourOfDay":21,"minuteOfHour":20,"secondOfMinute":56,"millisOfSecond":807,"millisOfDay":76856807,"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"id":"Europe/Berlin"}},"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"id":"Europe/Berlin"},"millis":1404242456807,"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false}}
```

It's quite hard to tell why this is happening, and I'm still not sure after digging around in `ObjectMapper`s, `JodaModule`, and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Any idea how to configure Spring to leverage both Spring Boot and be able to support matrix variables?

**Update**: Other breakages caused by scanning in `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` include Boot's `http.mappers.jsonPrettyPrint` support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/Spring41-and-Java8-Optional-as-RequestParam-RequestHeader-MatrixVariable.html), the following does the trick with Spring Boot 1.2.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);

        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just have to copy the bits you need from the boot autoconfiguration. Or raise an issue with Spring Framework to get support for the semicolon feature added to `WebMvcConfigurer`. One other thing that might just work is to add a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` directly (rather than using a base class for your config).